# Overriding virtual function not working, header files and c++ files

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, virtual

We have a parent class called Student. We have a child class: StudentCS.

Student.h:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<vector.h>
#include "Course.h"
class Course;

class Student {
public:
    Student();
    Student(int id, std::string dep, std::string image,int elective);
    virtual ~Student();
    virtual void Study(Course &c) const;  // this is the function we have a problem with
    void setFailed(bool f);
[...]

};
```

Student.cpp:

```
#include "Student.h"

[...]

void  Student::Study(Course &c) const {

}
```

And we have StudentCS.h:

```
#include "Student.h"
class StudentCS : public Student {
public:
StudentCS();
virtual ~StudentCS();
StudentCS (int id, std::string dep, std::string image,int elective);
void Study(Course &c) const;
void Print();
};
```

And StudentCS.cpp:

```
void StudentCS:: Study (Course &c) const{
    //25% to not handle the pressure!
    int r = rand()%  100 + 1;
cout << r << endl;
if (r<25) {
    cout << student_id << " quits course " << c.getName() << endl;
}

 }
```

We create student in the main:

```
Student *s;
vector <Student> uniStudent;
[...]
    if(dep == "CS")
        s = new  StudentCS(student_id,dep,img,elective_cs);
    else
        s = new StudentPG(student_id,dep,img,elective_pg);

    uniStudent.push_back(*s);
```

Then we call to study, but we get the parent study, and not the child!
Please help!

The code compiles but when run and called on the uniStudent.Study() it uses the parent and not the child

Comment: will you ever call the student virtual function normally in your program? it might be a good idea to make student an abstract base class and set study to a pure virtual function.

Comment: There are functions in student that we will use. When I tried to make study a pure virtual function by doing: [Virtual void Study(Course &c) =0;] and erasing the implantation in the .cpp file it didn't compile.

Comment: It didn't compile for sure, since the parent method is called it means that virtual invokation doesn't work, hence `StudentCS` misses its vtable.

Comment: You haven't made it clear that StudentCS derives from Student, although being able to assign the pointer without casting implies that it does. I'm tempted to believe this code doesn't represent your actual problem.

Comment: edited it now to show most of StudentCS.h ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT: after your edit the problem is clear.

The problem is that you are storing base concrete objects in a STL container. This creates a problem called [object slicing](http://login2win.blogspot.it/2008/05/c-object-slicing.html).

When you add a student to a `vector<Student>`, since the allocator of the vector is built on the `Student` class, every additional information on derived classes is just discarded. Once you insert the elements in the vector they become of base type.

To solve your problem you should use a `vector<Student*>` and store directly references to students in it. So the allocator is just related to the pointer and doesn't slice your objects.

```
vector<Student*> uniStudent;
...
uniStudent.push_back(s);
uniStudent[0]->study();
```

Mind that you may want to use a [smart pointer](http://ootips.org/yonat/4dev/smart-pointers.html) to manage everything in a more robust way.

Comment: ok I edited it a bit now to make things more clear the problem is with the vector uniStudent I want each of its cells to have diffrent types of Students and call on the study function from that type

Comment: but now how would I call a function of uniStudent? 

uniStudent[0].study() does not work it did before?  

*uniStudent[0].study() does not work either??

Comment: since they are pointers you need to use the correct (`->`) operator to access members of the object.